# Fixing line wrap using OS X terminal window

Tags: macos, editing, pico

I'm new to Mac OSX but I've used BSD "boxes" to successfully run an old newsreader called TRN on. We did manage to get it to compile and it runs pretty well normally. The latest problem I have is with line wrapping.

Usenet news articles need line wrap to work properly or anyone following up your articles ends up with a mess of unquoted text since it went out on one line. I could do constant hard returns, but that is not the answer.

Below is how my older .profile file looked which wrapped lines perfectly and never gave me any edit problems. I've no clue what half of it means or does since my admin would make these edits and have my shell working perfectly. I'm even less able to figure it out on this Mac.

This was what my old .profile looked like.

```
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/bin; export PATH
#stty erase    
stty dec
export PS1="\u@\h.whatever.net \d \t \w \n"
case `id -u` in
       0) PS1="${PS1}# ";;
       *) PS1="${PS1}% ";;
esac
export TERM=vt100
stty -hupcl
PAGER=more ; export PAGER
export NAME="me myself"
EDITOR=pico ; export EDITOR
crt=53 ; export crt
#ENV=$HOME/.shrc ; export ENV
```

So, my adding this to a .profile I create in my home directory with OS X does nothing to cure the long lines. What am I doing wrong? I've tried fiddling with my bashrc and that does not seem to do anything either as looking at my draft I see the end result of this post isn't formatting like I'd like it to.

Comment: Most of that .profile file has absolutely nothing to do with formatting. You seem to be talking about writing text files, which is dependent on your *editor*, not your .profile settings. Could you clarify whether you are looking for wrapping text *as saved from an editor* (pico?), or looking for wrapping text *as displayed on the terminal*?